# Catch when Android application went on background

Tags: android

I need help with Android.
Here is problem I need to catch event when application went to background.
(ex. home is pressed or any other action that push my app in backgound)
Currently I'm able to catch onPause for activity

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
}
```

Is there any override for some event on application level ?

Comment: Not sure what you're after.  OnPause is the notification you will get when your activity loses focus. Take a look at the documentation for more details:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Comment: This is whole story, I need to show splash screen (logo) when aplication is resumed from background. So I need to know when application went in background, knowing when one activity loses focus will not help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your comment it sounds like you want to know when your program returns from the background, instead of when it goes to the background.

You can use `onResume` for that. also, see the [Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle). You can see the remark "activity comes to the foreground", which is what I gather from your comment the thing you want.

*Note: your activity will call `onResume` the first time the activity is started, so you might want to set a boolean in onPause to signal your app that it actually went to the background.*

Comment: My app currently have 5 activites. I have override onPause/onResume on each activity, what I want is when user press home and use some other app (my app is in background) and when user press icon for my program he will go to activity where app was left and this is what I want to change. Only when my app is returning from background to show splash screen otherwise I have onPause/onResume for each activity some other action. something like onPause/onResume but for Application not for activity

Comment: What is the problem? In the onPause, save somewhere permanent that you have gone to sleep, and what activity was running. In your onresume you can reset that status, and show the splash. If you have been shutdown because of memory issues, then your oncreate is called. That checks if there was a previous activity, what it was, etc. Check out the manual for livecycles and how to restart your activity with a saved state.

Comment: How do I know that app went to sleep, not the activity, because when user use app, he goes through actvitys like activity1 -> activity2 -> activity3 -> activity4 -> activity3 -> activity4 -> acticity5 -> acticity4 -> acticity3 -> acticity2 -> acticity3 -> now he press home and whole app is in background. How do I know that after activity3 catch onPause it not because activity4 is getting focus (onResume) but whole app is in background.

Comment: I sorry if I can't explain my problem, I found this on stackoverflow MyApp app = (MyApp) getApplication(); app.setUpBeforeClosingApp(); and I wander if there are other undocumented events on Application that have event like onPause/onResume on Application

Comment: thanx for help Nanne, I solve this by adding one static variable and on each activity (there are 10) override onResume/onBackPressed and onClick for every button on every activity add some code to test if onResume is called from my action or from application onResume. I still think there should be easy way to do that if android had Application onPause/onResume