# JQuery Mobile app generic doubts

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am new to JQuery mobile .
Need some assistance to start with.

My plan is for a mobile application( cross platform android and Iphone ) which will get and update data to a webservice. This will be a set of htmls. I need to access gallery and camera so i think it should be integrated with PhoneGap.

- Now the html pages are hosted in same domain as web service. While
  integrating to Phonegap would like to know whether i need to move
  Html to app or keep the htmls in remote server and put a web view to
  load html from there. Basically in samples i have seen the app itself
  with htmls , so would like to know best strategy.
- In Android app there is a hardware back button. Basically i have
  a login page, home page and detail pages. While in Home page if hardware back
  button is pressed , i should ask for logout . I searched but dint get
  idea to handle the same.
- May be i will remove camera functionality and then it will be pure
  JQuery Mobile and no Phonegap. SO this will be loaded in browser
  directly in device. So if in JQuery mobile only also , can this hardware back
  button be handled.

Please guide me in right direction.

-Thanks in advance
mia

Answer (score 1):

In reply to your first point: the practice of hosting the full html pages in a remote server is usually forbidden by the app stores (at least iOS having read the guidelines recently).
You should instead only retrieve data from the server (in the form of json/xml for instance). For this very purpose you can create your mobile app using Backbone, or any other MVC/MVVC platform.
Your base pages will be in the app -displayed by phonegap webview- along with some templates. Every time the user goes to another page, you fetch some json data from the server and then process your data with the templates to generate full html.

This process makes more sense than serving full html pages (which is then more a mobile site than a mobile app) as only the data (what is dynamic) is sent from the server, which makes the payload smaller (better for mobile devices with limited bandwidth capabilities).

For the second point, I guess you mean when the app is closed or put in the background through this back button you want to call a logout function in your app. You'll need to catch a [system event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5156067/catch-when-android-application-went-on-background), but that's not something you can handle directly in Phonegap and you'll need some native java coding for that.. but first check the [phonegap plugins](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android) for such feature but I haven't seen any.

For the third point, if you say you don't want to use phonegap your 'mobile app' will become only a 'mobile site'. which is fine, but then you'll have even less control over that "back button". You'll only be able to control web events like window close (beforeunload).

Comment: thakyou for the comments. For second point and 3rd point  , i mean user goes from login to home page after succesful login . And then if clicks hardware backbutton , he will actually go to login page. This is not expected behavior. We should prompt a logout or remain in same home page when we clicks cancel.

Answer (score 1):

1. It is possible to have the full HTML on the server and I have had an app approved for the iOS app store with this method. However there are obvious downsides including the fact that you lose off-line capabilities.
2. You can add an event listener for the back button `document.addEventListener('backbutton', onBackButton, false);`
3. As far as I know you cannot handle the back button with a mobile site.

Comment: for your first point, here is the iOS guideline point I was thinking about:

2.12 Apps that [..] are simply web sites bundled as apps, [..] may be rejected

Comment: I know there is a guideline regarding web apps. However if you are making use of device functionality which justifies it actually being an app (such as camera, etc) then the app can still be approved. It is not a black & white situation where wrapping remote HTML means your app will be rejected.